# passing column name in ST_GeomFromText instead of value

Tags: postgresql

Below query works fine for me

```
select ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-111.7844620 32.9667050)',4326) from elec_common.abc;
```

geometry column has same value as above which is -111.7844620 32.9667050
however the below query shows an error

```
select ST_GeomFromText('POINT(geometry)',4326) from elec_common.abc;
```

> SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry 
>    Hint:
>   "POINT(ge" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: parse error - invalid
>   geometry
>    Hint: "POINT(ge" <-- parse error at position 8 within
>   geometry

Comment: I resovled the issue

Comment: select ST_GeomFromText('POINT('||geometry||')',4326) from elec_common.abc a; works